# grpc: does grpc provide efficient way to access server within the same process?

Tags: grpc

If the client and server reside in the same process, is there some shortcut for efficient access? For example, no message marshaling, direct function call, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has an in-process transport (InProcessChannelBuilder and InProcessServerBuilder) that is able to avoid serialization. If you use directExecutor() on both client and server then it becomes closer to "direct function call".

C++ has an in-process transport as well (InProcessChannel() on Server), but it will serialize and deserialize messages. Since most C-based languages use mutable protocol buffers, even if it could avoid serialization it would still need to make a copy of some sort; Java's protocol buffers are immutable.

Comment: what about golang?

Comment: Go does not have an in-process transport, especially not one avoiding message serialization. You can pretty easily hook up your own in-process "loopback" by providing your own dialer and listener, though.